# Is it possible to get a physical copy of Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

Is Rocket League available on physical media, or is it only the digital copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Psyonix's Vice President Jeremy Dunham [recently announced](http://www.polygon.com/2016/2/24/11109850/rocket-league-retail-release) that Rocket League will be coming to stores soon.

Unfortunately, no price point or released date has been given.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:** This information was true at the time, but Rocket League has since been announced to arrive in physical form (see *Powerlord*'s answer).

You cannot (as of yet).

According to the devs ([source](https://twitter.com/rocketleague/status/610564019443793920)), Rocket League is download only.